# Zeta function representation in terms of bosonic/fermionic degrees of freedom

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Consider Euler's product representation of the zeta function

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-p_i^{-s}},$$

with $\text{Re}(s)>1$, and $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime number, i.e. $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5,...$

Now, if we think of $s$ as the inverse (complex) temperature and $\epsilon_i=\log p_i$ as the energy of an exotic Bose particle in "quantum state" $i$. Then, the right hand side of the above equation could be considered as a partition function of an ideal gas of identical (exotic) Bose particles (see "Bose-Einstein statistics").

On the other hand, the product representation of the correponding (exotic) fermionic partition function, say $\zeta_F(s)$, is equal to (Fermi-Dirac statistics)

$$ \zeta_F(s)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+p_i^{-s}).$$

1. What is the series representation of $\zeta_F(s)$ in analogy to $\zeta(s)$?
2. What is the corresponding analytical continuation for $\zeta_F(s)$?
3. Is this approach encouraging?

Comment: $\zeta_F(s)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+p_i^{-s})^{{\color{red}{-1}}}?$

Comment: No, there is no minus sign. See http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss2/fermigas/thermo/thermo.php

Comment: By imagining "multiplying out" the terms of the product representation of $\zeta_F(s)$, one can immediately see that $\zeta_F(s) = \sum_{\text{square-free}} 1/n^s$, where the sum is over all square free integers $n$.

Comment: In fact (someone correct me if I'm wrong), I believe it's the case that $\zeta_F(s) = \zeta(s) / \zeta(2s)$. Edited to add: Playing around numerically in Mathematica does suggest that this relation is correct, at least for $s>1$.

Comment: Indeed, the computation of the infinite product in Mathematica gives $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$. And from Titchmarsh p.5, we know that  $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s}$.

Comment: So would the latter expression constitute the desired series representation of $\zeta_F(s)$?

Comment: Yes, and this answeres my first question. But what about question 2? Is that trivial now?

Comment: Yes, I think the continuation of $\zeta_F(s)$ is just the same as that of $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$. As for question 3: Encouraging in what sense? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I find it very interesting in which way the fermionic degrees of freedom are reflected in the remaining terms of the sum of the zeta-function representation. Actually, I was contemplating with an alternative connection between the primedistribution $\pi(x)$ and a certain zeta-like function.